# Angle between two vectors

Tags: delphi, math

So, I'm trying to get the angle between two TPoints in Delphi, and it turns out to be harder then what I expected. The result I'm getting I can't explain (seems to be some problem with "to degrees"-part, or ArcTan2 does not return a sum in the form I expected. 
- Delpi-v7:

```
function Modulo(x,y:Extended): Extended;
var d: Extended;
begin
  d := x / y;
  Result := (d - floor(d)) * y;
end;

function Degrees(Rads: Extended): Extended;
begin
  Result := Rads*(180/Pi);
end;

function GetPointAngle(P1, P2: TPoint): Extended;
begin
  Result := Modulo(Degrees(ArcTan2(-(P1.Y - P2.Y), P1.X - P2.X)) - 90, 360);
end;
```

Yet, when I port the code to Python, or test it in another Pascal-variant, the above **works**. But now, it seems to return a sum that's static (not changing if I "move" the second TPoint).

In case your wondering; I created "modulo"-function simply because the divide-operator used in the "mod"-operator rounds to 0, and not down (so negative numbers don't work).

Edit: I noted that the value (angle) returned from `GetPointAngle()` increases when `p` gets further away from the other point `c` (and vice versa), even tho the TPoint (`p`) is dragged along the X-axis of the second TPoint (`c`).

**EDIT**:

You guys have outdone your self, I've looked over most of the answers, and it seems to be hard to choose best answer! And since you guys wrote everything with such detail, I will go trough everything with the same detail :-)

Also: what I did not share in my initial post, is that my function is being exported as a DLL to be reached from another pascal-interpretor (which is delphi-compatible).

**Solution at last** (changed):

`GetPointAngle(P1, P2: TPoint)` To: `GetPointAngle(const P1, P2: TPoint)`

^ *I don't understand the need of declaring constants...*

Comment: What do you mean by "angle between two points"? Do you mean angle between the two vectors?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "angle between two points"

Comment: My mistake, between a set of coordinates.

Comment: @SLACKY That still doesn't make it clear

Comment: Well, I dont know the definition of a vector. But I can give an example of two coordinats: `C=10,10`, `P=10,50`, (x,y) like in a picture, if you catch my drift. So the angle between C, and P = 90 degrees. Or in my Post/use it would/should equal 0 degrees.

Comment: There is no angle between two points. You need two lines to define an angle. To I guess you want the angle between the vertical line, and a line between your two points. As described in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Yes of course, I get it now! My math aint all that good. But this answers will expand my knowledge :)

Comment: Unless the distance between the two points is réally big, there's no need for using `Extended`. Furthermore, `Extended` is a Delphi-specific value type, and considering you export this routine from a DLL, I strongly advise to use `Double`.

Comment: I agree 100% with @NGLN. The main thing you will find with `Extended` is that it makes your code slower.

Comment: I was not aware that Extended was a Delphi-specific type, and that it is slower than double. Thanks for the tips! :)

Comment: @SLACKY In 32 bit Delphi, Extended maps to the x87 80 bit floating point type. In MSVC that's long double. But there's invariably  no point using it. It also only exists for 32 bit targets. The 64 bit compiler uses the SSE FPU which only has 32 and 64 bit types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to calculate the angle relative to the X-axis of the line which is formed between those two points.

[image]

For this situation, the following formula applies:

```
Tan(a) = (P2.Y - P1.Y) / (P2.X - P1.X)
```

Which translates to:

```
a = ArcTan((P2.Y - P1.Y) / (P2.X - P1.X))
```

When the two points have the same X coordinate, this will obviously result in a `EDivByZero` exception, so  you have to take care of that yourself. Furthermore, `ArcTan` results in an angle within the range 0°..90° (i.e. 0..π/2) and thus disregards the correct quadrant, while `ArcTan2` results in an angle within -180°..180°. Add 360° to the result to convert a negative angle to positive:

```
function AngleOfLine(const P1, P2: TPoint): Double;
begin
  if P2.X = P1.X then
    if P2.Y > P1.Y then
      Result := 90
    else
      Result := 270
  else
    Result := RadToDeg(ArcTan2(P2.Y - P1.Y, P2.X - P1.X));
  if Result < 0 then
    Result := Result + 360;
end;
```

Which results in:

```
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(20, 10)); // 0
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(20, 20)); // 45
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(10, 20)); // 90
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(0, 20));  // 135
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(0, 10));  // 180
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(0, 0));   // 225
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(10, 0));  // 270
  A := AngleOfLine(Point(10, 10), Point(20, 0));  // 315
```

Now, this is relative to the world coordinate system which has its positive Y-axis pointed upwards by default. If you want to convert the result to the device coordinate system wherein the positive Y-axis points downwards, then subtract the result from 360°:

```
Result := 360 - Result;
```

#### Update:

It seems `ArcTan2` dóes take care of division by zero, (even in D7 inspite of the documentation) so the routine becomes much simpler:

```
function AngleOfLine(const P1, P2: TPoint): Double;
begin
  Result := RadToDeg(ArcTan2((P2.Y - P1.Y),(P2.X - P1.X)));
  if Result < 0 then
    Result := Result + 360;
end;
```

#### Edit:

> I noted that the value returned from `GetPointAngle()` increases when `p` gets furter away from the other point `c` (and vice versa).

That depends. Looking at the diagram above, if the second point moves further along the x-axis, the angle decreases. If the second point moves further along the y-axis, the angle increases. Of course, this depends on which quadrant both points are in.

Furthermore, your code negates the first parameter of `ArcTan2` and subtracts another 90° from the result. I do not know what you mean by that and whether it is intentional, but it could be the source of unexpected results.

Comment: You've done a decent job explaining the maths here, although you switched from atan to atan2 without an explanation. It would be good to expand on that. However, the code in the answer is the same as the code in the question, modulo that you measure against horizontal, and the question measures against vertical. At least it should be clear to SLACKY how to reason about the problem. It's a real shame  when a question is asked that misses critical information, and then the asker vanishes!

Comment: @David Thanks, I added some more explanation. Indeed a pitty OP doesn't expand on his question. It could be ignorance. I once asked a question, being sure I had given everything. Next day: well, it was best to delete it in all embarrassment. ;)

Comment: Negating first argument measures clockwise rather than anti clockwise. Subtracting 90 measures from verical rather than horizontal.

Comment: I'm sorry about the "vanishing"-part. I will do some testing, it's still some unclearity as to why my initial code/math failed, there is from what I see, nothing wrong with it(?). I exported the functions to be reached from another pascal-interpetor, and that is probably the cause of the function failing.

Answer (score 4):

I presume what you are looking for is the angle between two vectors. That is θ in this diagram:

[image]

The algebraic dot product can be expressed geometrically as <v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>> = |v<sub>1</sub>||v<sub>2</sub>|cos θ. This can be rearranged to find θ = cos<sup>-1</sup> <v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>>/(|v<sub>1</sub>||v<sub>2</sub>|).

```
function DotProduct(const v1, v2: TPoint): Integer;
begin
  Result := v1.X*v2.X + v1.Y*v2.Y;
end;

function Magnitude(const v: TPoint): Double;
begin
  Result := Sqrt(Sqr(v.X)+Sqr(v.Y));
end;

function AngleBetweenVectors(const v1, v2: TPoint): Double;
var
  Magv1, Magv2: Double;
begin
  Magv1 := Magnitude(v1);
  Magv2 := Magnitude(v2);
  if abs(Magv1*Magv2)=0.0 then
    Result := 0.0
  else
    Result := ArcCos(EnsureRange(DotProduct(v1,v2)/(Magv1*Magv2), -1.0, 1.0));
end;
```

That returns an angle in radians. You can convert that into degrees using `RadToDeg()` from the `Math` unit.

Now, the other way to interpret your problem is that you want to take two points and form the line between then. And then find the angle between that line and the horizontal, say. As described by this diagram:

[image]

The can still be expressed as the angle between two vectors. The first vector is p<sub>2</sub>-p<sub>1</sub> and the other is a vector in the horizontal direction, (0, 1). Feed those two into `AngleBetweenVectors` and you have your answer. If you want to measure angle to vertical, then you can use the same idea.

Hopefully there's enough here for you to solve the problem, whatever it actually is.

Comment: Hint: create a circular arc by selecting 'Arc' and holding down Alt when you place it. Then use the yellow selector to make it essentially 360°. Then make sure to place it with its origin at the intersection of the two lines. Finally, use the yellow markers to adjust the arc to lie between the two lines only. One problem with this approach is that the invisible part of the arc object [will occupy a lot of space](http://superuser.com/questions/343938/how-to-draw-angles-in-word), but since you only create a PNG screenshot of the document, that won't be an issue.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you. As you can tell, I am less familiar with Word than I am with development tools.

Comment: Well, as you can tell from my SuperUser questions, or my [long report](http://www.datormagazin.se/media/201206/Word2010_buggar_insandare.pdf) on using Word to write a physics textbook, Word sure can be a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

Following code returns same results with Delphi 7 and FPC 2.7.1 and it seems correct.
So main question is: what we are expecting and what we are having?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
    Math;

{.$define speed}

function CalcAngle(const lx, ly: extended): extended; {$ifdef speed} inline; {$endif}
begin
    Result := RadToDeg(ArcTan2(ly, lx));
end;

function Modulo(x, y: extended): extended; {$ifdef speed} inline; {$endif}
var
    d: extended;
begin
    d := x / y;
    Result := (d - floor(d)) * y;
end;

function Degrees(Rads: Extended): Extended;
begin
  Result := Rads*(180/Pi);
end;

function Modulo2(x: extended): extended; {$ifdef speed} inline; {$endif}
begin
    if x < 0 then
        Result := 360 + x
    else
        Result := x;
end;

function GetPointAngle(const lx, ly: integer): Extended;
begin
    Result := Modulo(Degrees(ArcTan2(ly, lx)) - 90, 360);
end;

procedure OutTest(const lx, ly: extended);
var
    a: extended;
begin
    a := CalcAngle(lx, ly);
    Writeln(
        a: 10: 4,
        Modulo(a - 90, 360):10:4,
        GetPointAngle(round(lx), round(ly)):10:4);
end;

begin
    OutTest(2, 0);
    OutTest(0, 2);
    OutTest(-2, 2);
    OutTest(-2, -2);
    OutTest(2, 3);
    OutTest(100, 2);
    Readln;
end.
```